# Как извлечь ответ нейронной сети формата pytorch в c++?

Tags: c++, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, pytorch

Я обучил keras модель и затем сконвертировал её в pytorch используя [mmdnn](https://pypi.org/project/mmdnn/). Затем я попробовал использовать её в c++ коде:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <torch.h>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat image;
    image= cv::imread("test_img.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);   // Read the file

try
{
    torch::jit::script::Module module;
    module = torch::jit::load("my_model.pth");

    torch::IntArrayRef input_dim = std::vector<int64_t>({ 1, 2, 256, 256});

    cv::Mat input_img;
    image.convertTo(input_img, CV_32FC3, 1 / 255.0);
    torch::Tensor x = torch::from_blob(input_img.data, { 1, 2, 256, 256 }, torch::kFloat);
    torch::NoGradGuard no_grad;

    auto output = module.forward({ x });

    float* data = static_cast<float*>(output.toTensor().data_ptr());

    cv::Mat output_img = cv::Mat(256, 256, CV_32FC3, data);
    cv::imwrite("output_img.png", output_img);
}
catch (std::exception &ex)
{
    std::cout << "exception! " << ex.what() << std::endl;
}

    return 0;
}
```

В результате запуска получено исключение:

> exception! isTensor() INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at
>   E:\20B\pytorch\pytorch\aten\src\ATen/core/ivalue_inl.h:112, please
>   report a bug to PyTorch. Expected Tensor but got Tuple (toTensor at
>   E:\20B\pytorch\pytorch\aten\src\ATen/core/ivalue_inl.h:112) (no
>   backtrace available)

Исключение было выброшено в строке `float* data = static_cast<float*>(output.toTensor().data_ptr());` при вызове функции `toTensor()`. Если использовать вместо неё `toTuple()`, то получившийся объект не имеет метода `data_ptr()`, который нужен мне для получения данных, содержащих ответа нейронной сети (и чтобы затем поместить их в картинку opencv для последующего её сохранения).

Как всё-таки извлечь картинку из ответа нейронной сети?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае ответ нейронной сети содержит массив (tuple) блобов, поэтому для их извлечения в виде тензоров нужно использовать следующие вызовы:

```
torch::Tensor t0 = output.toTuple()->elements()[0].toTensor();
torch::Tensor t1 = output.toTuple()->elements()[1].toTensor();
```

Теперь в переменных `t0` и `t1` тензоры с двумя ответами нейронной сети.